# Getting the value of the closest dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I have 3 radiobuttons that are created from a `foreach` loop.  2 out of the 3 radiobuttons will have a textbox that is a select2 dropdown.  When the user clicks continue I want to get the value from the closest dropdown list (select) to the checked radiobutton.  For testing purposes I'm just trying to alert the value.  However, when I click Continue `Undefined` is appearing in the alert.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
foreach (var formEType in Model.FormETypes)
{
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-check d-flex align-items-center">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FormETypeId, formEType.FormETypeId, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                <label class="form-check-label edit-item">
                    <b>@formEType.Name</b><br />
                    <span class="text-muted">
                        @Html.Raw(formEType.Description)
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        @if (formEType.FormETypeId != FormETypeCode.Appointment)
        {
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label class="font-weight-bold">Officer</label>
                <select name="IndividualId" class="form-control search"></select>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="continue">Continue</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#continue').on('click', function () {
            var checkedRadio = $('input[name=FormETypeId]:checked', '#FormE');

            if (checkedRadio.val() == '@FormETypeCode.Separation' || checkedRadio.val() == '@FormETypeCode.StatusChange') {
                var closestOfficer = checkedRadio.nextAll('input').val();

                alert(closestOfficer);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
 var checked = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
 var textbox = checkedRadio.closest("div").next('div').find('select');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be closest `select`.  I'm going to update the title.  I tried `.find('select') in addition to what you have and both are undefined.

Comment: Try : var textbox = checked.closest("div.form-check").find('select');

Comment: Undefined unfortunately.  Does it matter that it's a `select` and not an `input`?

Comment: it shouldn't be . in order for this to work both need to be in same div as per documentations. Can you try it with input meanwhile

Comment: I tried with input and it didn't work.  I also tried `var textbox = checked.closest('div')` and then `textbox.addClass('border-danger')` (just to see what div was being selected) and it's adding the class to the div with the class `.form-check`.  I think `.closest` is selecting the wrong div and that's why it can't find the input.

Comment: that is why closest("div.form-check") should select .form-check div but it also not working i guess

Comment: I think I just found the issue - I accidentally put the `select` outside the end `</div>` of `.card-body`.  Fixing the html now and going to test

Comment: I got it working.  Here's what I had to do: `var textbox = checkedRadio.closest("div").next('div').find('select');`  Thank you for your help!

Comment: sure .. i ll update the answer